# Why doesn't Patchwerk take fatigue damage?

Tags: hearthstone

In the solo adventure Naxxramas the first boss on the fourth wing Patchwerk takes no fatigue damage. Was this intentional or just a bug? This happens on the normal and the Heroic version.

[image: Patchwerk Naxxramas]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is intentional. The bosses in Adventure Mode don't always play by the rules.

Patchwerk starts with no deck but he does not attempt to draw a card at the start of his turn. This means he won't normally take fatigue damage.

However, Patchwerk is **not** immune to fatigue. If an effect does cause him to draw cards, such as Coldlight Oracle's battlecry, he will attempt to draw them and take fatigue damage as a normal player would.

Comment: A single Jeeves will cause Patchwerk to instantly die from fatigue.

Comment: @freekvd Have you actually tested this? I've heard that it simply causes him to attempt to draw 3 cards. Still brutally effective of course- 21 damage over 2 turns and a kill at 3- but not instant.

Comment: Just tried it, and apparently you are right. That's weird though, considering his card text.